# Consulta con LIKE no funciona Pyhton Sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Aquí tengo la consulta

```
if len(self.nombre1.get()) != 0 and len(self.apellido1.get()) == 0:
        query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE NOMBRE1 LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE ORDER BY NOMBRE1 Desc'
        parameters=(self.nombre1.get(), )
```

Esta consulta no me generar error, pero la instrucción LIKE no funciona como esperaba, si coloco el nombre completo (Juan) como esta en la tabla aparece y filtra peri si colo (Jua) no aparece nada muestra el resultado vació, mi pregunta es si la instrucción LIKE funciona con ?

Comment: Como ya te respondieron, sólo voy a agregar un par de comentarios: el marcador posicional `?` que usas indica que la sentencia preparada espera un valor allí. Adicionalmente, el marcador posicional no opera sobre los valores a comparar, ni en él se pueden usar comodines (`?%` genera error). Los comodines para búsqueda se deben integrar dentro de los valores. ej: `Jua%ez` permite encontrar a Juan Perez y a Juanita Ramírez: empieza en 'Jua' y termina en 'ez' con cualquier cosa en medio.

Comment: Ok entiendo, ahora si el valor a comparar es introducido por el usuario, es por ello que usa ?, que me recomiendan para que la sentencia de consulta busque y asocie por lo introducido por teclado, ahora funciona solo si el usuario introduce el nombre completo.

Comment: No. `?` se usa para crear una sentencia preparada de modo que haya un buen nivel de seguridad al pasar el valor a la consulta que se enviará a la BD. Y, significa que se asociará un valor al query reemplazando la interrogación en `WHERE NOMBRE1 LIKE ?` por el mismo. Para agregar el comodín puedes hacer algo como `parameters = (self.nombre1.get() + "%", )` de esa manera la consulta buscando Jua responderá mostrando Juan, Juana, Juanita, Juaco etc.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó perfecto., muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La instrucción `LIKE` funciona de igual forma que `=` si no se usa con el operador `%`.

Es decir que:

`NOMBRE1 LIKE 'Juan'` es lo mismo que `NOMBRE1 = 'Juan'`.

Para hacer lo que quieres seria asi:

`NOMBRE1 LIKE 'Jua%'` Esto te buscaría todos los que empiezan con `'Jua'`.

Se puede usar de muchas otras formas el `%`.